# Is there a formula I can use to show the top 10 values with criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, list

I am looking for a formula that will give me the top 10 $ amount from a column, however it must match a category from another column. I have attached an example of what I need.

In this example I am looking for the
Top 10 Order $ of New/Hot

[image]

Comment: Filter, Sort then take the top 10.

Comment: a pivot table could also work

Comment: LARGEIF function?